# How to override prototype rendering in Symfony2

Tags: jquery, symfony

IF I am embedding a form type Collection in a form. I have set allow_add to true. How is it possible to override the prototype  output. Say I want to wrap the collection of form types in a table on each add. Figured I can play around with the prototype output in jquery but would much rather get this right from the start. As an example my collection is of type:

```
class EmailShareType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       $builder->add("shareName","text",array("label"=>"Recipient Name:"));
       $builder->add("emailName", "email", array("label"=>"Recipient Email:","required" => true));
       $builder->add("emailMessage", "textarea",array("label"=>"Enter email message", "max_length" => "4000"));
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return 'emailShare';
    }    
}
```

and the resulting prototype is rendered as:

```
data-prototype="
<div>
<label class="required">__name__label__</label>
<div id="emailShareCollection_emailShares___name__">
<div>
<label for="emailShareCollection_emailShares___name___shareName" class="required">Recipient Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="emailShareCollection_emailShares___name___shareName" name="emailShareCollection[emailShares][__name__][shareName]" required="required" />
</div>
<div>
<label for="emailShareCollection_emailShares___name___emailName" class="required">Recipient Email:</label>
<input type="email" id="emailShareCollection_emailShares___name___emailName" name="emailShareCollection[emailShares][__name__][emailName]" required="required" />
</div>
<div>
<label for="emailShareCollection_emailShares___name___emailMessage" class="required">Enter email message</label>
<textarea id="emailShareCollection_emailShares___name___emailMessage" name="emailShareCollection[emailShares][__name__][emailMessage]" required="required" maxlength="4000"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>"
```

How do I get control over this output?

Comment: You have to override the rendering of form.
You can read about it here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can render it as you want by passing a `custom template` :

```
data-prototype="{% filter escape %}{% include 'YourBundle:YourController:yourTemplate.html.twig' with {'form': form.collectonField.get('prototype')} %}{% endfilter %}"
```